# Using webpack Encore, DataTables responsive button is not showing

Tags: webpack, datatables

I have a DataTable and I want to use the [Responsive extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive).

I set up my DataTable:

```js
import 'datatables.net-responsive';

$(function () {
    let myTable = $('#my-list').DataTable({
        responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column',
                target: 'tr'
            }
        },
        // ...
    });
    myTable.draw();
});
```

The columns are collapsing under a new line, appearing on row click but there isn't any button like the [one in the documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/whole-row-control.html).

I found a [discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/69239/responsive-expand-green-button-not-showing-how-can-i-go-about-it-please) in which someone explains we need to include the extension CSS file but there isn't any CSS in the `node_module/datatables.net-responsive` folder. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [DataTables Responsive GitHub ReadMe](https://github.com/DataTables/Dist-DataTables-Responsive) is stating:

> Only the core software for this library is contained in this package - to be correctly styled, a styling package for Responsive must also be included. Styling options include DataTable's native styling, Bootstrap and Foundation.

In my case, I installed the Bootstrap 5 style:

`yarn add datatables.net-responsive-bs5`

Then I included it in my SCSS file:

```scss
@import '~datatables.net-responsive-bs5';
```

And now the button is showing.